# (VB.NET) Change images on TreeView

Tags: vb.net, treeview

I have a tree view TreeView1 which works fine and 2 images in ImageList1 the first image (0) is a folder and the second image (1) is a file icon. I can't seem to get the icons to be folders for folders and files for files. They are always all folder icons or always file icons. Below is my code. Any ideas?

```
...
...
...
    '==================== LOAD FOLDERS FROM SELECTED DIRECTORY ====================
    Public Sub LoadDirectory(ByVal Dir As String)
        Dim di As DirectoryInfo = New DirectoryInfo(Dir)
        Dim Tree1 As TreeNode = TreeView1.Nodes.Add(di.Name)
        Tree1.Tag = di.FullName
        Tree1.StateImageIndex = 0
        LoadFiles(Dir, Tree1)
        LoadSubDirectories(Dir, Tree1)
    End Sub
    '==================== LOAD SUB-FOLDERS FROM SELECTED DIRECTORY ====================
    Private Sub LoadSubDirectories(ByVal dir As String, ByVal td As TreeNode)
        Dim subdirectoryEntries As String() = Directory.GetDirectories(dir)
        For Each subdirectory As String In subdirectoryEntries
            Dim di As DirectoryInfo = New DirectoryInfo(subdirectory)
            Dim Tree2 As TreeNode = td.Nodes.Add(di.Name)
            Tree2.StateImageIndex = 0
            Tree2.Tag = di.FullName
            LoadFiles(subdirectory, Tree2)
            LoadSubDirectories(subdirectory, Tree2)
        Next
    End Sub
    '==================== LOAD FILES FROM SELECTED DIRECTORY ====================
    Private Sub LoadFiles(ByVal dir As String, ByVal td As TreeNode)
        Dim Files As String() = Directory.GetFiles(dir, "*.*")

        For Each file As String In Files
            Dim fi As FileInfo = New FileInfo(file)
            Dim Tree3 As TreeNode = td.Nodes.Add(fi.Name)
            Tree3.Tag = fi.FullName
            Tree3.StateImageIndex = 1 '*** Not changing to Index 1 which is "File" Icon ***
        Next
    End Sub
```

When I run this code, all folders and files show the icon at index 0 which is a "folder" icon in the ImageList. The code I think is the issue is each of the `Tree.StateImageIndex = 1` or `Tree.StateImageIndex = 0` but maybe I am missing something? I want folders to be the image at index 0 and and files to be the image at index 1.

Comment: [How to: Set Icons for the Windows Forms TreeView Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/how-to-set-icons-for-the-windows-forms-treeview-control?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8).

Comment: Read also these [Remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.treenode.stateimageindex?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=windowsdesktop-7.0#remarks) to understand what the state image feature is for, when and how to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is `TreeView.StateImageIndex` is incorrect and should be just `TreeView.ImageIndex` and then everything will work. In addition, one also needs `TreeView.SelectedImageIndex` set, otherwise when you click and highlight a node it'll change to the image at index 0.